# Angular2 EventEmitter subscription does not work after navigate and come back

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I emitted the data from `MerchantComponent`

[image]

and subscribed via `EventEmitterService` from `MerchantPaymentChannelComponent`, its OK when route directly opens this page. But you see there is other tabs which every tab has its own components. When I change the tab to different one, then come back to this `MerchantPaymentChannelComponent` its not subscribe again.

**NOTE**: I'm doing unsubscription on `NgOnDestroy` event

Here is codes;

***MerchantListDetailService (SHARING SERVICE VIA EVENTEMITTER)***

```
export class MerchantListDetailService {
 @Output() emittedMerchant: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

 constructor() {}

 emitMerchant(data) {
    this.emittedMerchant.emit(data);
 }

 getEmittedValue() {
    return this.emittedMerchant;
 }
}
```

***MerchantComponent (TRIGGERING EMIT FROM THIS COMPONENT)***

```
 private getMerchantDetail() {
   let data = {
     Id: this.merchantId,
   }
   this.merchantsService.getMerchants(data)
     .then((res) => {
       // console.log(res)
       if (res.Success) {
         this.merchant = res.Data[0];
         this.merchantListDetailService.emitMerchant(res.Data[0]);
       }
     })
     .catch((err) => { })
 }
```

***MerchantPaymentChannelComponent (SUBSCRIBING FROM THIS COMPONENT)***

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.merchantSubscribe = this.merchantListDetailService.getEmittedValue()
  .subscribe(merchant => {
    this.merchant = merchant;
    this.getMerchantPaymentChannels();
  })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.merchantSubscribe.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: because component will initiate again. You need to implement state management

Comment: I didn't understand, can you be more specific?

Comment: when you navigate back and forth your component will be calling `ngOnInit()` again. so all the components and data will be instantiated again.

Comment: but I already bootstrap it in the main module. For the emitter service, there is only one instance that feeding data from any component

Comment: it will be initiated again.

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: State management is the solution and scope is big